# Illustrator. Delete pattern tile. Add new color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am a starter in illustrator. 1)How can I delete a pattern tile from swatches? Is it possible? 2)How can I add new colors to color swatches? Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I like the desire to learn that you are showing. A suggestion- at the top of this web page is a search field that is a really good resource- many of these questions have answers that someone else has posted already and going through them is a great way to learn.

Comment: Please only ask as single question per, well, question. There's some info and guidelines in the [help] that you might want to look at. Thanks!

Comment: Merry, you are in the right place to get help, but you need to help us so that we can.  Please provide screenshots of what you are trying to do / have done / where you are at.  A lot of the questions you are asking are meaningless without the context of being able to see what you are seeing.  At this point, there is a reason none of your questions have answers, and Admin is really trying to work with you, so please work with us.

Answer (score 0):

With nothing selected click on the pattern tile swatch you want to delete and click on the trash can icon at the bottom right of the swatches panel. If the panel is not showing go to Window> Swatches to show the panel.

To add a new color (or pattern) to the swatches panel there is a square box with a + inside at the bottom of the swatches panel next to the trash can icon. Another way is to open the Color Panel (Window> Color) and click on the dropdown menu in the top right corner of the panel and choose "Create New Swatch".